# is it possible to use retrieving history (or document state) as a navigation in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, microsoft-edge

I'm worrying that I won't get any reply from stack overflow, because I couldn't get any reply from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418818/saving-history-object-with-iframe-in-browser). You don't need to fully read previous question, but It could be helpful to understand my question.

Our company is on service that html document builder(windows application) and I'm a desktop s/w engineer. after build html document with our windows app, we export all things to html/js/css.

Consumer of our application is a designer who creates or edits contents via our windows app. and the end-user of contents which is created by designer see contents via browser(chrome, safari (iphone), samsung browser).

The Problem is, my superior (programmer) wants use `java-script` as a navigation, this is possible. but,  he want to save all state of document state before navigation, so after navigation to any page and then comeback to origin page, all state - animation (contents may have animation) and all script state - should be same exactly before he leaving origin page.

More specifically, main html has a `iframe`, and `iframe` can shows all contents. `Main.html` have a navigation button so `iframe` can navigate all contents created by designer. If user interacted with `page1.html` inside `iframe`, then make `iframe` to change its content to `page2.html` by clicking navigation button (`go to second page` button implemented inside `main.html` but outside of `iframe`). and then back to `page1.html`, he get exactly same state as before he leaving `page1.html`.

At a glance, It seems quite possible just implement go-forward or go-backward, but dynamically paging navigation is impossible to me. I found some techniques - access browser `visit history` and `window.history` object, but It seems there isn't user-defined way.

I thought **Electron app(desktop)** will be fine for our solution, but my superior says It should be works well with just html/js/css. Our final product should be shown in desktop, iPad, mobile or any device that handle web browser.

I need technical advice to accomplish this issue, I'm fine there is no way to control navigation while saving document state. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document state can be saved by using localstorage object in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful to retrieve exactly same state before leaving previous page. but what our superior want is navigation between all `.html` fully saving state.

Comment: Thanks Arijit, you edited your answer. but I don't understand what you suggested. may I ask you to describe any approach, specifically?

Comment: @JeongYoHan you could refer to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) about `localStorage`. You could set items in `localStorage`. Data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, you could reuse it anytime when you navigating the pages.

Comment: @YuZhou, Thank you. but How I can save all document state - not a specific element - with `localStorage`? `localStorage` is a just storage for variable, not a way to represent all state of document. I need to memorize total document state. I tried with InnerHTML of iframe - but It does not contains input element state. or element state that is changed background color.

Comment: @JeongYoHan If you want to keep the page as it was first visited why don't you just use the browser navigation button? If you navigate with JavaScript, then the page will be refreshed. And if you are presenting a blank form, the user enters some data and then without submitting it, refreshes the page, there is nothing you can do. If the user submits the changes before leaving the page, then you can store the states in database, hidden areas of the page or in localstorage one by one.

Comment: @YuZhou, Thank you for detailed advice. I'm on finding a way to implement auxiliary browsing context which is written in w3c docs to save my own history state. but as you described, I might need to store attributes of all element in each page before navigating to another page, with recursion and iteration...The reason of this implementation is simple, need a solution- like as history is saving all state of document, or behaving like a static class in object oriented language.

Comment: I'll choose this answer is the only way that I can try. And I'm working on it. Parsing all elements and save it session storage . and retrieve them all.